# DNS lookup fails but nslookup works

Tags: macos, dns, osx-snow-leopard, hosts

I have DNS lookup problems on my internal network. I'm using an internal DNS server with the IP 192.168.1.254.

If I use nslookup everything works like it should:

```
>hawk:~ user$ nslookup publicwebserver.domain.local
>Server:        192.168.1.254
>
>Address:   192.168.1.254#53
>
>Name:  publicwebserver.domain.local
>
> Address: 192.168.1.21
```

My problem is that no other program seems to be able to lookup the DNS name:

> hawk:~ user$ ping publicwebserver.domain.local
>
> ping: cannot resolve publicwebserver.domain.local: Unknown host

It's like this for all command line programs and e.g. Firefox. If I fire up Network Utility, I get the same problem on the Lookup tab (probably since it uses nslookup or host on the back-end).

Has any of you seen this issue before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems as if this is due to me pointing to both internal and external dns servers on my client, as mentioned [here](http://www.winvistatips.com/re-dns-problem-nslookup-works-fien-but-ping-does-not-t733030.html). After I removed all external DNS servers from my list of servers, everything works as it should.

Comment: Is it a link to a Windows Vista forum???

Answer (score 8):

For some, check /etc/resolver/ directory and delete any files there.

Comment: I had a leftover dnsmasq installation (to resolve *.localhost to 127.0.0.1) that I removed in favour of configuring it at my router level (using dd-wrt, via dnsmasq options under Services). The only thing I hadn't removed was the `/etc/resolver/` folder that I had created during the local dnsmasq install. So, this solution worked for me

Comment: omg THANK you. A rogue installer took it upon itself to resolve .dev domains to localhost

Answer (score 6):

Actually it is probably due to using a *.local* domain. That [conflicts with the mDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local) resolution (zero configuration networking) which by default uses *.local*.

Some versions of OS X can support both name resolution methods, mDNS and normal DNS, but at least Yosemite doesn't seem to support it any more.

This little bit older [Apple Support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3473?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) explains the background. For Yosemite what does work still is adding "domain.local" to the DNS search list in the network settings.

The real solution is not using the *.local* domain for DNS resolved hosts.

Comment: This solved it for me (not using .local in my dns zone settings). I am using OSX Yosemite.

Comment: Yes, worked for me as well. Switched from .local to .vpn and voila, it works! I also have to mention that nslookup worked before switching from .local (still does!), just ping didn't work (now does).

Comment: That Apple support link is dead now. Any new links on how to make this change?

Comment: Just don’t use a .local domain for your LAN. That is already reserved for use with mDNS. You may still be able to override this with a search domain in the DNS settings, but I wouldn’t count on it. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh14127/13.0/mac/13.0

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes mDNSResolver stops when connecting with VPN.

Just restart the mDNSResolver:

`sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

Comment: This worked for me after changing my DNS server on my local LAN

Comment: Using macbook also this worked for me. After changed some entries on the DNS ssh was not resolving them. This trick kinda refresh the cache!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on OS X Yosemite beta, and switching to Google's `8.8.8.8` fixed the problem for me.